# control rabbitmq 'name' not 'sname'

Tags: crash, erlang, osx-lion, rabbitmq, startup

On lion OS, after installation, when running, error happens. 
At first, not using `rabbitmq-env.config file`, starting by `"sudo rabbitmq-server"`, the following message shows:

```
yus-iMac:rabbitmq yuchen$ sudo rabbitmq-server
Activating RabbitMQ plugins ...

********************************************************************************
********************************************************************************

0 plugins activated:

ERROR: epmd error for host "yus-iMac": address (unable to establish tcp connection)
```

Then I add `rabbitmq-env.conf` file. The content is as follows:

```
RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbitb@yus-iMac.local

When starting, another error message is given:

yus-iMac:rabbitmq yuchen$ sudo rabbitmq-server
Activating RabbitMQ plugins ...

********************************************************************************
********************************************************************************

0 plugins activated:

{error_logger,{{2012,5,26},{21,47,13}},"Can't set short node name!\n Please check your configuration\n",[]}
```

I think the message means short node can't be used. But I don't know how to control `rabbitmq-server` for using `name`, rather than `sname`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Search on Google found [this link](http://codingiscoding.wordpress.com/2011/04/17/rabbitmq-on-os-x/), which should fix the problem you see at the beginning.
Here's the relevant part in case it become inaccessible:

> making sure that your machine name (rs-mbp in my case) is in /private/etc/hosts

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost rs-mbp
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

Comment: Due to chinese country's firewall, the above link of wordpress.com can't be visited. After finding rabbitmq-server is a script file, I opened the file, and find in the last paragprah, -sname is hardcoded. After modifying the source code of 'rabbitmq-server, the problem has been solved.

Comment: I feel sorry for that. The part of the blog had been updated in the answer.

Comment: Where do you find your "machine name"?

Comment: The machine name could be find by executing the command `hostname` in shell.