# unable to start rabbitmq-server

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

I installed rabbitmq using homebrew. I am trying to start rabbitmq server but I always get this error which I am unable to figure out why!

I have erlang installed and there is no other application running on the same port.

```
$ rabbitmq-server 
{error_logger,{{2013,2,11},{22,37,49}},"Can't set short node name!\nPlease check your configuration\n",[]}
{error_logger,{{2013,2,11},{22,37,49}},crash_report,[[{initial_call,{net_kernel,init,['Argument__1']}},{pid,},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,{error,badarg},[{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,320}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,227}]}]}},{ancestors,[net_sup,kernel_sup,]},{messages,[]},{links,[]},{dictionary,[{longnames,false}]},{trap_exit,true},{status,running},{heap_size,610},{stack_size,24},{reductions,249}],[]]}
{error_logger,{{2013,2,11},{22,37,49}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,net_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,{'EXIT',nodistribution}},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{name,net_kernel},{mfargs,{net_kernel,start_link,[[rabbitmqprelaunch1593,shortnames]]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,2000},{child_type,worker}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2013,2,11},{22,37,49}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,kernel_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,shutdown},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{name,net_sup},{mfargs,{erl_distribution,start_link,[]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,infinity},{child_type,supervisor}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2013,2,11},{22,37,49}},std_info,[{application,kernel},{exited,{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}},{type,permanent}]}
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,kernel,{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,kernel,{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}})
```

btw, `erl -sname abc` gives the same output

**Update**:

This is what I have in `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
```

Comment: Does using a long name work?

Comment: you mean instead of `localhost`? nope!

Comment: How about `erl -name abc@abc`?

Comment: did u eventually get this working? running into the exact same issue and spent the past hour looking for it.  no one else seems to have the same issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked for a similar error on google, and it looks like it can happen if your `/etc/hosts` file is in the wrong format.  Try fixing it and see if that helps.

References:

- http://www.ejabberd.im/node/18
- [Explanation on RabbitMQ Mailing list](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.networking.rabbitmq.general/16135)

---

Edit: For completeness, it seems like setting a long name (of the form `abc@abc`) worked.

Comment: all i have in /etc/hosts is 

127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost

Answer (score 4):

check your computer name and your short host name or alias name in /etc/hosts, match this

- Check your computer name `[wendy@nyc123]$`
  nyc123 is your computer name
- Check your short hostname

  [wendy@nyc123]$ hostname -s

  [wendy@nyc123]$ nyc456

This error could happen because your computer name and short host name didn't match. To match this, you can change the computer hostname or alias name.

- Change computer host name

  [wendy@nyc123]$ hostname nyc456

  close your terminal and open again
  [wendy@nyc456]$ 
  the computer name has changed

or

- Change alias name in /etc/hosts

  127.0.0.1     nyc123.com     nyc123

  save and check again

  [wendy@nyc123]$ hostname -s

  [wendy@nyc123]$ nyc123

Restart your rabbitmq!

```
[root@nyc123]$ rabbitmq-server start</p>


    RabbitMQ 3.6.0. Copyright (C) 2007-2015 Pivotal Software, Inc.</p>
##  ##      Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/</p>
##  ##</p>
##########  Logs: /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbitmq@nyc123.com.log</p>
######  ##        /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbitmq@nyc123.com-sasl.log</p>
##########</p>
          Starting broker... completed with 6 plugins.</p>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Since the original poster is on OS X, there needs to be an entry in `/etc/hosts` for `127.0.0.1` that matches the output of `hostname -s`

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here:
[control rabbitmq 'name' not 'sname'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767037/control-rabbitmq-name-not-sname)

Set your machine name to something simple and make it an alias to locahost

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem yesterday and found the root cause:
I had changed my system's hostname to a "long" name, pm3(hc desktop).

If your server's hostname is long or invalid, Linux can still work and no error message is prompted to you. As you just modify the /etc/hostname file and reboot. However, the rabbitmq server may not work and give this "short-name" error message to you.

I changed hostname back to "pm3", rebooted and everything went well.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue changing the computer name (on windows 8.1). The problem was that the name had a strange character (é) spanish letter. My computer name was Andrés and I changed it to Andres, restarted my computer and everything worked well. I think that Rabbit could not recognize that name (Andrés) for that strange character.

Answer (score 0):

remove old style config file /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
and use rabbitmq.conf 
with `listeners.tcp.default = 5672`
after that restart rabbitmq server again
In my case that solved the issue in ec2 instance